# HTACCESS redirect a URL with query string in it

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Basically you can visit `/stats.php?player=name` by simply typing in `https://domain.com/@name` and it works perfectly. But I also need the old `/stats.php?player=name` links to redirect to `https://domain.com/@name`.

How do I do this? Below is my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^@(\w+)$ stats.php?player=$1
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, where you are already rewriting the "pretty" URL to the "ugly/real" URL you can *redirect* the ugly URL to the pretty URL by checking against `THE_REQUEST`. This contains the original HTTP request, before any rewriting has occurred. Otherwise you are in danger of creating a rewrite loop when you rewrite back to the ugly URL. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?player=(\w+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^stats\.php$ /@%1? [R=301,L]
```

External redirects should generally come before internal rewrites.

Checking for "stats.php" in the `RewriteRule` pattern, rather that in the `RewriteCond` directive lessens the load on the server by not processing every single request (the `RewriteRule` is processed first). `%1` refers to the first parenthesised sub pattern in the `RewriteCond` pattern. And the trailing `?` (an empty query string) essentially removes the query string from the rewritten substitution.

I would also append the `L` flag and make your current `RewriteRule` root-relative by prefixing with a slash (assuming this file is in the root of your site). Relative URLs can be problematic in .htaccess files:

```
RewriteRule ^@(\w+)$ /stats.php?player=$1 [L]
```

Also, move the `Options` and `RewriteEngine` directives to the top:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?player=(\w+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^stats\.php$ /@%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^@(\w+)$ /stats.php?player=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

(I've also snuck a slash in the last `RewriteRule` substitution as well. If you use *relative* URLs then you should also specify a `RewriteBase` directive.)

The check for `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` is also probably unnecessary. Unless you specifically only want to set an `ErrorDocument` and `Options` if this module is available?!

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your informative post - I had high hopes for it, but sadly I get a redirect loop on stats.php while this .htaccess is uploaded. Does it have anything to do with the site being HTTPS?

Comment: I noticed it takes you to domain.com/@name?player=name

Comment: Ah yes - oops! It needs a single `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution in order to chop off the query string! I've also appended an `[L]` flag to your existing rewrite. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hey thanks! :) Do I re-add the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> so that my 404 page works again (404.php)? it currently redirects to index.php now.

Comment: The `<IfModule` check is really superfluous for mod_rewrite. If mod_write isn't installed, the directives are simply ignored anyway and presumably it is already installed on your server or nothing would be working? (TBH it's a bit of a puzzle why it is so often used.) I can't see off hand why your 404 page is being redirected? It does exist? This is presumably for when you access a non existent page, rather than accessing the `404.php` page directly?

Comment: My 404.php file exists - but even typing it in directly redirects to index.php

Comment: And it worked before?! What does "404.php" contain? Anything to cause a redirect?? Try commenting out (temporarily removing) everything apart from the `ErrorDocument` directive. (You can comment out lines by prefixing with a `#`.) Does it work now?